# Постоянное обращение к жесткому диску

Tags: hdd, linux

Доброго времени суток, есть такая проблема. Установил bactrack5, после чего идет постоянное обращение к жесткому диску, iotop показывает, что идет запись на диск jbd2, я так понимаю это журналирование. Гугл ответа не дал, отключать журналирование как то не охото.

Answer (score 3):

Доброго. BT5 = Ubuntu 10.04 LTS с доработанным ядром. jbd2 - это не диск, а служба [Journaling Block Device](http://kerneltrap.org/node/6741) - журналирование устройств с поблочным доступом. Файловую систему вы не указали, предположу, что это ext4. Просто загуглив "jbd2", нашел пару ссылок, [первая](http://www.nrtm.de/index.php/2012/06/06/jbd2-forces-frequent-hard-drive-wake-ups/) и [вторая](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/607560), обе на английском.В двух словах и по-русски -  совсем эту jbd2 отрубать не рекомендуется, если у вас точно ext4, правьте /etc/fstab (типа `sudo nano /etc/fstab`), добавьте в конце строк с разделами ext4 commit=N, N = время в секундах между интервалами слива журнала на диск:

```
...UUID=820b416a-993f-4fe9-8191-a9453efaa923    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro,commit=180    0    1...
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но, к сосжелению, не помогло, запись продолжается. Действительно забыл указать ФС, ext4.

Answer (score 0):

Привет!Попробуй обновиться.Тут backtrack 5 r3 на днях вышел. Вдруг поможет ; )

[Релиз BackTrack 5 R3: более 60 новых инструментов](http://www.xakep.ru/post/59154/).

Comment: Привет, обновился, проблема осталась)